# anomalous behaviour of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

wondering all about C,  can you demystify this

I am using turbo C

I have this code

```
scanf(“%d , %d”,&a,&b);
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
scanf(”%c”,&c);
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
```

then scanf for doesnt scan value of c

output is : 1,2

if I use this

```
scanf(“%d , %d”,&a,&b);
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
scanf(”%c ”,&c);//note a blank after %c
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
```

then it scan value of c.

output is 1,2 1,2

same code

```
scanf(“%d , %d”,&a,&b);
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
scanf(”%1s”,&c);
printf(“%d,%d”,a,b);
```

in this segment value of a will be displayed but value of b will be set 0

output is 1,2 1,0

can you explain the answers of both the questions.

didnt got the answers yet help me.......

Comment: Please show the input on which you're operating

Comment: Types are also important here.

Comment: When Eli asked you to exhibit input, he meant show us *exactly* what you type. *Are* you typing the input with letters and equals signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that no character is being scanned for `c` in the first case? I assume it is because you provide a unexhibited print statement and don't see anything.

Read the man page careful about the behavior of the %c specifier:

> c
>        Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); the next
>              pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room
>              for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added).  **The usual
>              skip of leading white space is suppressed.**  To skip white space
>              first, use an explicit space in the format.

[emphasis added]

If you input has a form like `1, 2 a` the first scan eats the `1 , 2` and leaves the `a`, at which point the second scan eats the *space*. Not sure how the second example *would* work in this case.

[Anon. is on the money about the third case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234328/anomalous-behaviour-of-scanf/2234338#2234338)

Answer (score 3):

In your last case, it's to do with where values are set up in memory.

The second `scanf` puts a string of length 1 at the address of `c` - that is, one character, followed by the null terminator.

Guess where the null terminator goes?